# How to make sure that a inner div does not go outside its container div flexbox with CSS/HTML only?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to insert content inside of an inner div (in this case an image), however despite having set the max-width and width and max-height and height of the container div (flex container), the inner div still goes outside the boarders covering the other elements (outside its own div).

How to make sure that any content I put inside of a div will never go outside the maximum area I am assigning to it with CSS or HTML?

In this case when I click my messages from the left navbar this is what I get:

[image]

```js
const ProfileForm = document.getElementsByClassName('profile_container');
const dash = document.getElementsByClassName('dashboard_buttons');
var index;
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dash.length; i++) {

  array.push(dash[i]);

  dash[i].onclick = function() {
    index = array.indexOf(this);

    ProfileForm[index].style.display = "block";

    var check = ProfileForm[index];

    for (var i = 0; i < ProfileForm.length; i++) {
      if (ProfileForm[i].style.display == "block" && ProfileForm[i] != check) {
        ProfileForm[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```css
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*    border: thick solid blue;*/
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  /*border: thick solid yellow;*/
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  /*    width: 100%;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*border: thick solid red;*/
  visibility: visible;
  /*background-color: #003580;*/
}


/*BUTTON BACKGROUND COLORS*/

.header_right_container_inner_center_button,
.header_right_container_inner_right_button {
  background-color: #febb02;
}


/*BUTTON HOVER COLORS*/

.header_right_container_inner_right_button:hover,
.header_right_container_inner_center_button:hover {
  background: #003580;
  color: white;
}


/* BUTTON FONT COLORS*/

.header_right_container_inner_center_button,
.header_right_container_inner_right_button {
  color: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  /*border: thick dotted blue;*/
  width: 120px;
  margin-top: -33%;
  margin-bottom: -33%;
  /*border-radius:50%;*/
}


/* HEADER START */

header {
  display: flex;
  /*    border: thick solid red;*/
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: thin solid black;
  padding: 9px;
  background-color: #003580;
}


/* HEADER LEFT SIDE */

.header_left_container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  /*    border: thick solid yellow;*/
  justify-content: center;
}

.header_left_container_inner_left {
  /*    border: thick solid green;*/
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header_left_container_inner_right {
  /*    border: thick solid green;*/
  display: flex;
  flex: 5;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}


/* HEADER RIGHT SIDE */

.header_right_container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 3;
  /*    border: thick solid yellow;*/
  justify-content: center;
}

.header_right_container_inner_left {
  display: flex;
  /*    border: thick solid green;*/
  flex: 4;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

li {
  /*    display:inline;*/
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.search_input_input {
  flex: 1;
  color: white;
  background-color: #003580;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 99px;
}

.search_input_widget {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #003580;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 6%;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 120px;
}

.header_right_container_inner_left_list {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header_right_container_inner_center {
  display: flex;
  /*    border: thick solid green;*/
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.header_right_container_inner_center_button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*    background-color: #E00000;*/
  border: 1px solid #003580;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  /*    color: white;*/
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
}

.header_right_container_inner_right {
  display: flex;
  /*    border: thick solid green;*/
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header_right_container_inner_right_button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #febb02;
  border: 1px solid #003580;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
}

select.select_city_header {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  /*    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);*/
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  background-color: #003580;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.main_dashboard_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  /*    color: white;*/
  /*border: thick solid red;*/
}

.left_navbar {
  height: 90vh;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #003580;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #003580;
}

.dashboard_buttons {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  padding: 12px 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-bottom: thin solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #003580;
  color: white;
}

.dashboard_buttons:hover {
  background-color: #39CCCC;
  color: white;
}

.dashboard_right_container_wrap {
  position: absolute;
  /*margin-top: 21%;*/
  overflow: auto;
}

.right_content {
  flex: 4;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  /*margin-top: 1467px;*/
}

.profile_container {
  border: thick dotted yellow;
  margin-bottom: 18%;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*justify-content: flex-start;*/
  /*align-items: center;*/
}

.profile_title {
  border: thick dotted red;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: 333;
  color: #003580;
  padding: 12px;
}

.profile_form {
  border: thin solid #003580;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*align-items: flex-start;*/
  width: 666px;
  height: auto;
}

.profile_internal_container {
  border: thin solid #003580;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 6px;
}

.label_profile_form {
  /*border: thick solid green;*/
  width: 120px;
}

.input_profile_form {
  /*border: thick solid green;*/
  width: 160px;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  border: transparent;
  margin-left: 33px;
}

#inp,
#inp2 {
  /*text-align: center;*/
  margin: auto;
  width: 240px;
}

.profile_form_dropdown {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  /*text-align-last:center;*/
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 33px;
}

.profile_save_button_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.profile_save_button {
  border: thin solid #003580;
  background-color: #003580;
  color: white;
  width: 180px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  margin: 33px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  cursor: pointer;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.profile_save_button:hover {
  background-color: #39CCCC;
  border: thin solid #39CCCC;
  color: white;
}

.ul_flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.my_properties_container {
  position: absolute;
}

.properties_dashboard {
  border: thick dotted green;
  flex: 1;
  width: 666px;
  max-width: 666px;
  height: 350px;
  max-height: 350px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.utilities_elements,
.utilities_image {
  /*border: thin solid red;*/
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 150px;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.properties_dashboard_container {}

.properties_detail_widget {
  border: thin dotted #003580;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  /*border: thin solid red;*/
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.property_details {
  margin-left: -6px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 333;
  text-align: center;
}

.properties_detail_label {
  margin-left: 6px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.prop_detail {
  max-width: 450px;
  max-height: 250px;
  margin: 33px;
  border: thick solid #003580;
}

.property_image_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.msg_image_wrapper {
  border: thick dotted purple;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.msg_image {
  border: thick dotted gray;
  max-width: 666px;
  max-height: 666px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/99c0db90d1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="images/33.png" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!--        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" >-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--load all styles -->
  <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body id="body">
  <! -- HEADER START -->
  <header>
    <! -- HEADER LEFT SIDE CONTAINER START -->
    <div class="header_left_container">
      <div class="header_left_container_inner_left">
        <img class="logo" src="images/1.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="header_left_container_inner_right">
        <form action="">
          <select class="select_city_header" name="emirate" id="emirate" style="border: 0;">
            <option value="prague">Prague</option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <! -- HEADER LEFT SIDE CONTAINER STOP -->
    <! -- HEADER RIGHT SIDE CONTAINER START -->
    <div class="header_right_container">
      <div class="header_right_container_inner_left">
        <ul class="header_right_container_inner_left_list">
          <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Residential</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">Commercial</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">Room</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">Short-Term</a></li>
          <!--I'll put in this 2 icons, monthly and daily-->
          <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><i class="far fa-envelope" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>Inbox</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="search_input_widget">
          <i class="fas fa-search" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search_input_input">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header_right_container_inner_center">
        <button class="header_right_container_inner_center_button">Login</button>
      </div>
      <div class="header_right_container_inner_right">
        <button class="header_right_container_inner_right_button">Place Your Ad</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <! -- HEADER RIGHT SIDE CONTAINER STOP -->
  </header>
  <! -- HEADER STOP -->
  <div class="main_dashboard_container">
    <div class="left_navbar">
      <div class="sub">
        <ul class="ul_flex">
          <li class="dashboard_user_widget"><span class="span" style="min-height:350px;">&nbsp;</span></li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="profile_id"><i class="far fa-user" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>Profile</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="properties_id"><i class="far fa-list-alt" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>My Properties</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="bids_id"><i class="far fa-money-bill-alt" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>My Offers</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="utilities_id"><i class="fas fa-file-contract" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>My Utilities & Ejari</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="favourite_id"><i class="far fa-heart" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>Favourite Properties</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="messages_id"><i class="far fa-envelope" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>Messages</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="settings_id"><i class="fas fa-cogs" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>Settings</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_content">
      <div class="dashboard_right_container_wrap" style="position:absolute;">
        <div class="profile_container" id="profile_container" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Profile</h4>
          <form class="profile_form" id="profile_form">
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="name" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" class="input_profile_form">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Family Name" class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="nationality" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Nationality:</label>
              <select id="nationality" class="profile_form_dropdown">
                <option value="">Italy</option>
                <option value="">Germany</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="day" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Date of birth:</label>
              <select id="day" class="profile_form_dropdown">
                <option value="">22</option>
                <option value="">21</option>
              </select>
              <select class="profile_form_dropdown">
                <option value="">December</option>
                <option value="">January</option>
              </select>
              <select class="profile_form_dropdown">
                <option value="">1984</option>
                <option value="">2021</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="phone" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Phone number:</label>
              <input type="number" id="phone" placeholder="+97150...." class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="email" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email" class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="password" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="*******" class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="passport" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Passport:</label>
              <input type="text" id="passport" placeholder="Type Passport Number" class="input_profile_form">
              <input type="file" id="inp" class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="eid" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Emirates ID:</label>
              <input type="password" id="eid" placeholder="Type EID Number" class="input_profile_form">
              <input type="file" id="inp2" class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
          </form>
          <div class="profile_save_button_container">
            <button class="profile_save_button">Save</button>
          </div>
          <!--                        TODO all this part should first be autofilled with the user details and become a form exclusively if editing is needed-->
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_properties_container" style="display:none">
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Properties</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard_container">
            <div class="properties_detail_widget">
              <label class="properties_detail_label" for="address">Address:</label>
              <div class="property_details" id="address">Dubai Marina, Emaar Six Tower, Apt.1305</div>
              <label class="properties_detail_label" for="status">Status:</label>
              <div class="property_details" id="status" style="color:lawngreen; font-weight: bold">Rented</div>
              <label class="properties_detail_label" for="expiry">Expires:</label>
              <div class="property_details" id="expiry">17 Mar 2022</div>
              <label class="properties_detail_label" for="more_details">More:</label>
              <div class="property_details" id="more_details">More Details</div>
              <!--                                TODO all this part must be retrieved automatically from the database-->
            </div>
            <div class="property_image_wrapper">
              <img src="images/prop.jpg" class="prop_detail">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_bids" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Bids</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_utilities" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Utilities</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard">
            <div class="utilities_elements">
              <img class="utilities_image" src="images/Utilities Logos/dewa.png">
            </div>
            <div class="utilities_elements">
              <img class="utilities_image" src="images/Utilities Logos/du.png">
            </div>
            <div class="utilities_elements">
              <img class="utilities_image" src="images/Utilities Logos/etisalat.png">
            </div>
            <div class="utilities_elements">
              <img class="utilities_image" src="images/Utilities Logos/empower.png">
            </div>
            <div class="utilities_elements">
              <img class="utilities_image" src="images/Utilities Logos/ejari.png">
            </div>
            <div class="utilities_elements">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_favourites" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Favourites</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_messages" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Messages</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard">
            <div class="msg_image_wrapper">
              <img src="images/msg.PNG" class="msg_image">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_settings" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Settings</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

?

Comment: try .profile_container img { max-width: 100% }

Comment: tried, it did not work, the image still goes outside its area

Comment: I didn't see any image in your code, could you update it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not Sure if its what you are looking for.

Updated `.msg_image_wrapper` as seen below, this will force the image to conform to a specific height set by `max-height` property.

```
.msg_image_wrapper {
  border: thick dotted purple;
  /*display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;*/
  
  display: block; /* Added item */
  max-height: 350px; /* Added item */
  overflow: auto; /* Added item */
}
```

```js
const ProfileForm = document.getElementsByClassName('profile_container');
const dash = document.getElementsByClassName('dashboard_buttons');
var index;
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dash.length; i++) {

  array.push(dash[i]);

  dash[i].onclick = function() {
    index = array.indexOf(this);

    ProfileForm[index].style.display = "block";

    var check = ProfileForm[index];

    for (var i = 0; i < ProfileForm.length; i++) {
      if (ProfileForm[i].style.display == "block" && ProfileForm[i] != check) {
        ProfileForm[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*    border: thick solid blue;*/
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  /*border: thick solid yellow;*/
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  /*    width: 100%;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*border: thick solid red;*/
  visibility: visible;
  /*background-color: #003580;*/
}


/*BUTTON BACKGROUND COLORS*/

.header_right_container_inner_center_button,
.header_right_container_inner_right_button {
  background-color: #febb02;
}


/*BUTTON HOVER COLORS*/

.header_right_container_inner_right_button:hover,
.header_right_container_inner_center_button:hover {
  background: #003580;
  color: white;
}


/* BUTTON FONT COLORS*/

.header_right_container_inner_center_button,
.header_right_container_inner_right_button {
  color: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  /*border: thick dotted blue;*/
  width: 120px;
  margin-top: -33%;
  margin-bottom: -33%;
  /*border-radius:50%;*/
}


/* HEADER START */

header {
  display: flex;
  /*    border: thick solid red;*/
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: thin solid black;
  padding: 9px;
  background-color: #003580;
}


/* HEADER LEFT SIDE */

.header_left_container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  /*    border: thick solid yellow;*/
  justify-content: center;
}

.header_left_container_inner_left {
  /*    border: thick solid green;*/
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header_left_container_inner_right {
  /*    border: thick solid green;*/
  display: flex;
  flex: 5;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}


/* HEADER RIGHT SIDE */

.header_right_container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 3;
  /*    border: thick solid yellow;*/
  justify-content: center;
}

.header_right_container_inner_left {
  display: flex;
  /*    border: thick solid green;*/
  flex: 4;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

li {
  /*    display:inline;*/
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.search_input_input {
  flex: 1;
  color: white;
  background-color: #003580;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 99px;
}

.search_input_widget {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #003580;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 6%;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 120px;
}

.header_right_container_inner_left_list {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header_right_container_inner_center {
  display: flex;
  /*    border: thick solid green;*/
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.header_right_container_inner_center_button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*    background-color: #E00000;*/
  border: 1px solid #003580;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  /*    color: white;*/
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
}

.header_right_container_inner_right {
  display: flex;
  /*    border: thick solid green;*/
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header_right_container_inner_right_button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #febb02;
  border: 1px solid #003580;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
}

select.select_city_header {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  /*    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);*/
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  background-color: #003580;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.main_dashboard_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  /*    color: white;*/
  /*border: thick solid red;*/
}

.left_navbar {
  height: 90vh;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #003580;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #003580;
}

.dashboard_buttons {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  padding: 12px 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-bottom: thin solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #003580;
  color: white;
}

.dashboard_buttons:hover {
  background-color: #39CCCC;
  color: white;
}

.dashboard_right_container_wrap {
  position: absolute;
  /*margin-top: 21%;*/
  overflow: auto;
}

.right_content {
  flex: 4;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  /*margin-top: 1467px;*/
}

.profile_container {
  border: thick dotted yellow;
  margin-bottom: 18%;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*justify-content: flex-start;*/
  /*align-items: center;*/
}

.profile_title {
  border: thick dotted red;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: 333;
  color: #003580;
  padding: 12px;
}

.profile_form {
  border: thin solid #003580;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*align-items: flex-start;*/
  width: 666px;
  height: auto;
}

.profile_internal_container {
  border: thin solid #003580;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 6px;
}

.label_profile_form {
  /*border: thick solid green;*/
  width: 120px;
}

.input_profile_form {
  /*border: thick solid green;*/
  width: 160px;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  border: transparent;
  margin-left: 33px;
}

#inp,
#inp2 {
  /*text-align: center;*/
  margin: auto;
  width: 240px;
}

.profile_form_dropdown {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  /*text-align-last:center;*/
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 33px;
}

.profile_save_button_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.profile_save_button {
  border: thin solid #003580;
  background-color: #003580;
  color: white;
  width: 180px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  margin: 33px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  cursor: pointer;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.profile_save_button:hover {
  background-color: #39CCCC;
  border: thin solid #39CCCC;
  color: white;
}

.ul_flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.my_properties_container {
  position: absolute;
}

.properties_dashboard {
  border: thick dotted green;
  flex: 1;
  width: 666px;
  max-width: 666px;
  height: 350px;
  max-height: 350px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.utilities_elements,
.utilities_image {
  /*border: thin solid red;*/
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 150px;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.properties_dashboard_container {}

.properties_detail_widget {
  border: thin dotted #003580;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  /*border: thin solid red;*/
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.property_details {
  margin-left: -6px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 333;
  text-align: center;
}

.properties_detail_label {
  margin-left: 6px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.prop_detail {
  max-width: 450px;
  max-height: 250px;
  margin: 33px;
  border: thick solid #003580;
}

.property_image_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.msg_image_wrapper {
  border: thick dotted purple;
  /*display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;*/
  
  display: block; /* Added item */
  max-height: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.msg_image {
  border: thick dotted gray;
  max-width: 666px;
  max-height: 666px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/99c0db90d1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="images/33.png" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!--        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" >-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--load all styles -->
  <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body id="body">
  <! -- HEADER START -->
  <header>
    <! -- HEADER LEFT SIDE CONTAINER START -->
    <div class="header_left_container">
      <div class="header_left_container_inner_left">
        <img class="logo" src="images/1.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="header_left_container_inner_right">
        <form action="">
          <select class="select_city_header" name="emirate" id="emirate" style="border: 0;">
            <option value="prague">Prague</option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <! -- HEADER LEFT SIDE CONTAINER STOP -->
    <! -- HEADER RIGHT SIDE CONTAINER START -->
    <div class="header_right_container">
      <div class="header_right_container_inner_left">
        <ul class="header_right_container_inner_left_list">
          <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Residential</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">Commercial</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">Room</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">Short-Term</a></li>
          <!--I'll put in this 2 icons, monthly and daily-->
          <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><i class="far fa-envelope" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>Inbox</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="search_input_widget">
          <i class="fas fa-search" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search_input_input">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header_right_container_inner_center">
        <button class="header_right_container_inner_center_button">Login</button>
      </div>
      <div class="header_right_container_inner_right">
        <button class="header_right_container_inner_right_button">Place Your Ad</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <! -- HEADER RIGHT SIDE CONTAINER STOP -->
  </header>
  <! -- HEADER STOP -->
  <div class="main_dashboard_container">
    <div class="left_navbar">
      <div class="sub">
        <ul class="ul_flex">
          <li class="dashboard_user_widget"><span class="span" style="min-height:350px;">&nbsp;</span></li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="profile_id"><i class="far fa-user" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>Profile</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="properties_id"><i class="far fa-list-alt" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>My Properties</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="bids_id"><i class="far fa-money-bill-alt" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>My Offers</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="utilities_id"><i class="fas fa-file-contract" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>My Utilities & Ejari</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="favourite_id"><i class="far fa-heart" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>Favourite Properties</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="messages_id"><i class="far fa-envelope" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>Messages</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="settings_id"><i class="fas fa-cogs" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>Settings</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_content">
      <div class="dashboard_right_container_wrap" style="position:absolute;">
        <div class="profile_container" id="profile_container" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Profile</h4>
          <form class="profile_form" id="profile_form">
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="name" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" class="input_profile_form">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Family Name" class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="nationality" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Nationality:</label>
              <select id="nationality" class="profile_form_dropdown">
                <option value="">Italy</option>
                <option value="">Germany</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="day" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Date of birth:</label>
              <select id="day" class="profile_form_dropdown">
                <option value="">22</option>
                <option value="">21</option>
              </select>
              <select class="profile_form_dropdown">
                <option value="">December</option>
                <option value="">January</option>
              </select>
              <select class="profile_form_dropdown">
                <option value="">1984</option>
                <option value="">2021</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="phone" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Phone number:</label>
              <input type="number" id="phone" placeholder="+97150...." class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="email" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email" class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="password" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="*******" class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="passport" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Passport:</label>
              <input type="text" id="passport" placeholder="Type Passport Number" class="input_profile_form">
              <input type="file" id="inp" class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="eid" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Emirates ID:</label>
              <input type="password" id="eid" placeholder="Type EID Number" class="input_profile_form">
              <input type="file" id="inp2" class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
          </form>
          <div class="profile_save_button_container">
            <button class="profile_save_button">Save</button>
          </div>
          <!--                        TODO all this part should first be autofilled with the user details and become a form exclusively if editing is needed-->
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_properties_container" style="display:none">
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Properties</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard_container">
            <div class="properties_detail_widget">
              <label class="properties_detail_label" for="address">Address:</label>
              <div class="property_details" id="address">Dubai Marina, Emaar Six Tower, Apt.1305</div>
              <label class="properties_detail_label" for="status">Status:</label>
              <div class="property_details" id="status" style="color:lawngreen; font-weight: bold">Rented</div>
              <label class="properties_detail_label" for="expiry">Expires:</label>
              <div class="property_details" id="expiry">17 Mar 2022</div>
              <label class="properties_detail_label" for="more_details">More:</label>
              <div class="property_details" id="more_details">More Details</div>
              <!--                                TODO all this part must be retrieved automatically from the database-->
            </div>
            <div class="property_image_wrapper">
              <img src="images/prop.jpg" class="prop_detail">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_bids" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Bids</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_utilities" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Utilities</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard">
            <div class="utilities_elements">
              <img class="utilities_image" src="images/Utilities Logos/dewa.png">
            </div>
            <div class="utilities_elements">
              <img class="utilities_image" src="images/Utilities Logos/du.png">
            </div>
            <div class="utilities_elements">
              <img class="utilities_image" src="images/Utilities Logos/etisalat.png">
            </div>
            <div class="utilities_elements">
              <img class="utilities_image" src="images/Utilities Logos/empower.png">
            </div>
            <div class="utilities_elements">
              <img class="utilities_image" src="images/Utilities Logos/ejari.png">
            </div>
            <div class="utilities_elements">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_favourites" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Favourites</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_messages" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Messages</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard">
            <div class="msg_image_wrapper">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" class="msg_image">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_settings" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Settings</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this kind of what you wanted? I made 3 main changes, see the edited snippet below.

1. Added `box-sizing: border-box` to your global selector to help with your overlapping borders.
2. Added `object-fit: contain` to the image to contain it inside the bounds of the container
3. Added height/width to the container around the image to allow `object-fit` to work.

```js
const ProfileForm = document.getElementsByClassName('profile_container');
const dash = document.getElementsByClassName('dashboard_buttons');
var index;
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dash.length; i++) {

  array.push(dash[i]);

  dash[i].onclick = function() {
    index = array.indexOf(this);

    ProfileForm[index].style.display = "block";

    var check = ProfileForm[index];

    for (var i = 0; i < ProfileForm.length; i++) {
      if (ProfileForm[i].style.display == "block" && ProfileForm[i] != check) {
        ProfileForm[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*    border: thick solid blue;*/
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  /* Add box-sizing here to help with your borders overlapping */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  /*border: thick solid yellow;*/
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  /*    width: 100%;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*border: thick solid red;*/
  visibility: visible;
  /*background-color: #003580;*/
}


/*BUTTON BACKGROUND COLORS*/

.header_right_container_inner_center_button,
.header_right_container_inner_right_button {
  background-color: #febb02;
}


/*BUTTON HOVER COLORS*/

.header_right_container_inner_right_button:hover,
.header_right_container_inner_center_button:hover {
  background: #003580;
  color: white;
}


/* BUTTON FONT COLORS*/

.header_right_container_inner_center_button,
.header_right_container_inner_right_button {
  color: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  /*border: thick dotted blue;*/
  width: 120px;
  margin-top: -33%;
  margin-bottom: -33%;
  /*border-radius:50%;*/
}


/* HEADER START */

header {
  display: flex;
  /*    border: thick solid red;*/
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: thin solid black;
  padding: 9px;
  background-color: #003580;
}


/* HEADER LEFT SIDE */

.header_left_container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  /*    border: thick solid yellow;*/
  justify-content: center;
}

.header_left_container_inner_left {
  /*    border: thick solid green;*/
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header_left_container_inner_right {
  /*    border: thick solid green;*/
  display: flex;
  flex: 5;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}


/* HEADER RIGHT SIDE */

.header_right_container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 3;
  /*    border: thick solid yellow;*/
  justify-content: center;
}

.header_right_container_inner_left {
  display: flex;
  /*    border: thick solid green;*/
  flex: 4;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

li {
  /*    display:inline;*/
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.search_input_input {
  flex: 1;
  color: white;
  background-color: #003580;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 99px;
}

.search_input_widget {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #003580;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 6%;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 120px;
}

.header_right_container_inner_left_list {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header_right_container_inner_center {
  display: flex;
  /*    border: thick solid green;*/
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.header_right_container_inner_center_button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*    background-color: #E00000;*/
  border: 1px solid #003580;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  /*    color: white;*/
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
}

.header_right_container_inner_right {
  display: flex;
  /*    border: thick solid green;*/
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header_right_container_inner_right_button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #febb02;
  border: 1px solid #003580;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
}

select.select_city_header {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  /*    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);*/
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  background-color: #003580;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.main_dashboard_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  /*    color: white;*/
  /*border: thick solid red;*/
}

.left_navbar {
  height: 90vh;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #003580;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #003580;
}

.dashboard_buttons {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  padding: 12px 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-bottom: thin solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #003580;
  color: white;
}

.dashboard_buttons:hover {
  background-color: #39CCCC;
  color: white;
}

.dashboard_right_container_wrap {
  position: absolute;
  /*margin-top: 21%;*/
  overflow: auto;
}

.right_content {
  flex: 4;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  /*margin-top: 1467px;*/
}

.profile_container {
  border: thick dotted yellow;
  margin-bottom: 18%;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*justify-content: flex-start;*/
  /*align-items: center;*/
}

.profile_title {
  border: thick dotted red;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: 333;
  color: #003580;
  padding: 12px;
}

.profile_form {
  border: thin solid #003580;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*align-items: flex-start;*/
  width: 666px;
  height: auto;
}

.profile_internal_container {
  border: thin solid #003580;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 6px;
}

.label_profile_form {
  /*border: thick solid green;*/
  width: 120px;
}

.input_profile_form {
  /*border: thick solid green;*/
  width: 160px;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  border: transparent;
  margin-left: 33px;
}

#inp,
#inp2 {
  /*text-align: center;*/
  margin: auto;
  width: 240px;
}

.profile_form_dropdown {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  /*text-align-last:center;*/
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 33px;
}

.profile_save_button_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.profile_save_button {
  border: thin solid #003580;
  background-color: #003580;
  color: white;
  width: 180px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  margin: 33px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 333;
  cursor: pointer;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.profile_save_button:hover {
  background-color: #39CCCC;
  border: thin solid #39CCCC;
  color: white;
}

.ul_flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.my_properties_container {
  position: absolute;
}

.properties_dashboard {
  border: thick dotted green;
  flex: 1;
  width: 666px;
  max-width: 666px;
  height: 350px;
  max-height: 350px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.utilities_elements,
.utilities_image {
  /*border: thin solid red;*/
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 150px;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.properties_dashboard_container {}

.properties_detail_widget {
  border: thin dotted #003580;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  /*border: thin solid red;*/
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.property_details {
  margin-left: -6px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 333;
  text-align: center;
}

.properties_detail_label {
  margin-left: 6px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.prop_detail {
  max-width: 450px;
  max-height: 250px;
  margin: 33px;
  border: thick solid #003580;
}

.property_image_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.msg_image_wrapper {
  border: thick dotted purple;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  /* width and height need to be set here in order to properly contain the image */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.msg_image {
  border: thick dotted gray;
  /* max-width and max-height can just be 100% here as well since it inherits the size from it's parent */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  /* object-fit contain here will take any size image and contain it within the size of the container */
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/99c0db90d1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="images/33.png" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!--        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" >-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--load all styles -->
  <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body id="body">
  <! -- HEADER START -->
  <header>
    <! -- HEADER LEFT SIDE CONTAINER START -->
    <div class="header_left_container">
      <div class="header_left_container_inner_left">
        <img class="logo" src="images/1.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="header_left_container_inner_right">
        <form action="">
          <select class="select_city_header" name="emirate" id="emirate" style="border: 0;">
            <option value="prague">Prague</option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <! -- HEADER LEFT SIDE CONTAINER STOP -->
    <! -- HEADER RIGHT SIDE CONTAINER START -->
    <div class="header_right_container">
      <div class="header_right_container_inner_left">
        <ul class="header_right_container_inner_left_list">
          <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Residential</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">Commercial</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">Room</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">Short-Term</a></li>
          <!--I'll put in this 2 icons, monthly and daily-->
          <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><i class="far fa-envelope" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>Inbox</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="search_input_widget">
          <i class="fas fa-search" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search_input_input">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header_right_container_inner_center">
        <button class="header_right_container_inner_center_button">Login</button>
      </div>
      <div class="header_right_container_inner_right">
        <button class="header_right_container_inner_right_button">Place Your Ad</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <! -- HEADER RIGHT SIDE CONTAINER STOP -->
  </header>
  <! -- HEADER STOP -->
  <div class="main_dashboard_container">
    <div class="left_navbar">
      <div class="sub">
        <ul class="ul_flex">
          <li class="dashboard_user_widget"><span class="span" style="min-height:350px;">&nbsp;</span></li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="profile_id"><i class="far fa-user" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>Profile</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="properties_id"><i class="far fa-list-alt" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>My Properties</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="bids_id"><i class="far fa-money-bill-alt" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>My Offers</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="utilities_id"><i class="fas fa-file-contract" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>My Utilities & Ejari</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="favourite_id"><i class="far fa-heart" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>Favourite Properties</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="messages_id"><i class="far fa-envelope" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>Messages</li>
          <li class="dashboard_buttons" id="settings_id"><i class="fas fa-cogs" style="padding-right:9px;"></i>Settings</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_content">
      <div class="dashboard_right_container_wrap" style="position:absolute;">
        <div class="profile_container" id="profile_container" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Profile</h4>
          <form class="profile_form" id="profile_form">
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="name" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" class="input_profile_form">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Family Name" class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="nationality" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Nationality:</label>
              <select id="nationality" class="profile_form_dropdown">
                <option value="">Italy</option>
                <option value="">Germany</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="day" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Date of birth:</label>
              <select id="day" class="profile_form_dropdown">
                <option value="">22</option>
                <option value="">21</option>
              </select>
              <select class="profile_form_dropdown">
                <option value="">December</option>
                <option value="">January</option>
              </select>
              <select class="profile_form_dropdown">
                <option value="">1984</option>
                <option value="">2021</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="phone" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Phone number:</label>
              <input type="number" id="phone" placeholder="+97150...." class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="email" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email" class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="password" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="*******" class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="passport" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Passport:</label>
              <input type="text" id="passport" placeholder="Type Passport Number" class="input_profile_form">
              <input type="file" id="inp" class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
            <div class="profile_internal_container">
              <label for="eid" style="color: black;" class="label_profile_form">Emirates ID:</label>
              <input type="password" id="eid" placeholder="Type EID Number" class="input_profile_form">
              <input type="file" id="inp2" class="input_profile_form">
            </div>
          </form>
          <div class="profile_save_button_container">
            <button class="profile_save_button">Save</button>
          </div>
          <!--                        TODO all this part should first be autofilled with the user details and become a form exclusively if editing is needed-->
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_properties_container" style="display:none">
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Properties</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard_container">
            <div class="properties_detail_widget">
              <label class="properties_detail_label" for="address">Address:</label>
              <div class="property_details" id="address">Dubai Marina, Emaar Six Tower, Apt.1305</div>
              <label class="properties_detail_label" for="status">Status:</label>
              <div class="property_details" id="status" style="color:lawngreen; font-weight: bold">Rented</div>
              <label class="properties_detail_label" for="expiry">Expires:</label>
              <div class="property_details" id="expiry">17 Mar 2022</div>
              <label class="properties_detail_label" for="more_details">More:</label>
              <div class="property_details" id="more_details">More Details</div>
              <!--                                TODO all this part must be retrieved automatically from the database-->
            </div>
            <div class="property_image_wrapper">
              <img src="images/prop.jpg" class="prop_detail">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_bids" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Bids</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_utilities" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Utilities</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard">
            <div class="utilities_elements">
              <img class="utilities_image" src="images/Utilities Logos/dewa.png">
            </div>
            <div class="utilities_elements">
              <img class="utilities_image" src="images/Utilities Logos/du.png">
            </div>
            <div class="utilities_elements">
              <img class="utilities_image" src="images/Utilities Logos/etisalat.png">
            </div>
            <div class="utilities_elements">
              <img class="utilities_image" src="images/Utilities Logos/empower.png">
            </div>
            <div class="utilities_elements">
              <img class="utilities_image" src="images/Utilities Logos/ejari.png">
            </div>
            <div class="utilities_elements">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_favourites" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Favourites</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_messages" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Messages</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard">
            <div class="msg_image_wrapper">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/1500/1200" class="msg_image">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_container" id="my_settings" style="display:none">
          <!-- style="visibility: hidden;"-->
          <h4 class="profile_title">My Settings</h4>
          <div class="properties_dashboard">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```